# error using Autowired in AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to use an autowired object in my authenticationProvider but get an error. Without the use of the service object in the class there is not a problem, but ofcours I need the service object.

the customAuthenticationprovider class:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
@Autowired
private Service service;

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    if (service.LoginCorrect(name, password)) {

        // use the credentials
        // and authenticate against the third-party system
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(service.getPerson(name).getRole().role()));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                name, password, grantedAuths);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}}
```

Class where is use the custom provider:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("view.controller")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
}}
```

The Creation of the Bean:

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public Service service() {
    return new Service("JPADatabase");
}
}
```

The Initialize for the security:

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{ApplicationConfig.class, WebSecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{DispatcherServletConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Error message:

> Warning:   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider' defined in file [D:\Users\neuts\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project-ip-vincentneuts\spring-mvc-kopie\target\r0621919\WEB-INF\classes\view\controller\CustomAuthenticationProvider.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [view.controller.CustomAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class Autowired
>     location: class view.controller.CustomAuthenticationProvider
>   Severe:   Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider' defined in file [D:\Users\neuts\Documents\NetBeansProjects\project-ip-vincentneuts\spring-mvc-kopie\target\r0621919\WEB-INF\classes\view\controller\CustomAuthenticationProvider.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [view.controller.CustomAuthenticationProvider]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class Autowired
>     location: class view.controller.CustomAuthenticationProvider

EDIT: IT only works on the first run. (after restarting my glassfish server)

Answer (score 0):

From the exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code`, It's clear that this error is netbeans specific. I guess netbeans is using two different sources of "class file" data such that it can resolve all the symbols on a build, yet the runtime classpath and editor is using something different.

If you are using maven/gradle, try to build and run with it instead of your IDE. Or try cleaning netbeans caches.

Comment: Just found out that the projects runs, but only on the first run of my netbeans session.

Comment: update. it also works if i just restart my glassfish server. any idea how i can solve this problem?