# spring bean Autowired failed on redeploy

Tags: java, spring, jpa, autowired, glassfish-2.x

When I'm redeploying my application, netbeans run and maven (glassfish:redeploy). I got the following error:

> Warning:   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'service' defined in config.ApplicationConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [domain.service.Service]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: domain.model.Person@1b88ccf4 is not a known Entity type.

It only runs again, when I restart the glassfish server.

The persistence that I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="project_IP" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://***.***.***.**:1527/Chat2"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="u"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="p"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The code you can find here: [error using Autowired in AuthenticationProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820167/error-using-autowired-in-authenticationprovider/)

Reason I created a new thread is because this one is more specific.

Comment: if something "is now a known entity type" one would expect to need to post `persistence.xml`, and look in the LOG of the persistence provider to debug said issue

Comment: just  added persistence.xml @NeilStockton